# Add time onto datetime so it can be checked

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

I have a discord bot that can ban members from guilds and I wanted to make a temporary ban system, where the user gets banned, a certain amount of time passes and then they are unbanned. My current system is

```
await user.ban(reason=reason)
await asyncio.sleep(duration)
await user.unban()
```

This works perfectly, with no issues other than, when I restart the bot, the user would never be unbanned as the timer never finished.

Im thinking of using `datetime` and saving the time they get either "time of unban" or "time of ban and duration", but i cant figure out how to add/subtract the duration from the `datetime` and also how to compare datetimes to see if the time has expired.

Please could someone help me out and let me know how to manipulate datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python `datetime` module includes `timedelta` objects for handling offsets like you describe. For example, if you wanted to determine the time 10 seconds from right now:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> datetime.today() + timedelta(seconds=10)
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 29, 10, 15, 7, 675717)
```

Comment: Perfect, i guess that you could just use ">" to compare 2 datetimes to check if the time has expired?